# FilterScript in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 with PowerShell v5 and I've stumbled on some PowerShell behaviour I don't understand.

The following line working correctly and returning results as expected:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | where -Property "InstallState" -eq "Installed"
```

This working correctly and returning results as previous:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.Installed}
```

The following is **NOT** working, even though it should:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.Available}
```

But this one is working:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | where -Property "InstallState" -eq "Available"
```

I've seen the same behaviour with PowerShell v3 on Windows 7 as well.

Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Get-Member -MemberType Property

TypeName: Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.Feature

Name                      MemberType Definition                                                                                       
----                      ---------- ----------                                                                                       
AdditionalInfo            Property   hashtable AdditionalInfo {get;}                                                                  
BestPracticesModelId      Property   string BestPracticesModelId {get;}                                                               
DependsOn                 Property   string[] DependsOn {get;}                                                                        
Depth                     Property   int Depth {get;}                                                                                 
Description               Property   string Description {get;}                                                                        
DisplayName               Property   string DisplayName {get;}                                                                        
EventQuery                Property   string EventQuery {get;}                                                                         
FeatureType               Property   string FeatureType {get;}                                                                        
Installed                 Property   bool Installed {get;}                                                                            
InstallState              Property   Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.InstallState InstallState {get;}                        
Name                      Property   string Name {get;}                                                                               
Notification              Property   Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.ServerComponentManager.Internal.Notification[] Notification {g...
Parent                    Property   string Parent {get;}                                                                             
Path                      Property   string Path {get;}                                                                               
PostConfigurationNeeded   Property   bool PostConfigurationNeeded {get;}                                                              
ServerComponentDescriptor Property   psobject ServerComponentDescriptor {get;}                                                        
SubFeatures               Property   string[] SubFeatures {get;}                                                                      
SystemService             Property   string[] SystemService {get;}
```

There is no "Available" property.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've got it. The thing that confused me was property InstalledState that might has a value "Installed"， and Installed property